# What does Chakra "optimize" about KDE?

Tags: kde, distribution-choice

The KDE about box in Chakra says that I'm running "Platform Version 4.9.97 optimized by The Chakra Project". What exactly does Chakra "optimize" about KDE? I'm considering switching away (mostly due to the lack of packages because of the relatively small community) and I'd like to know if I'd loose anything.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning they display the same claim (still, with no clear/visible explanation) on their [site](http://www.chakra-project.org/): _Chakra provides a modular and tweaked package set of the KDE Software Compilation optimized for Chakra Linux and coming with a lot of useful additions._

Comment: Probably benign like a new default theme.

Comment: Marketing-speak for "we tweaked it a bit to our liking"?

Answer (score 1):

I see no optimization in the absence of gtk, I feel happier in any distro+kde with king-size repositories, from chakra I pick their artwork, is awesome.

Check out the designer's blog http://ext4.wordpress.com/ (spanish)